# Manejo de ramas en GitLab

Tags: git, gitlab, ingenieria-del-software

En la empresa donde trabajo usamos SVN como manejador de versiones, se tiene planificado migrar a GitLab, pero no estamos muy claros como debería ser el flujo de trabajo, tomando en cuenta lo siguiente:

1. Los analistas desarrollan tanto para resolver incidencias como para nuevos requerimientos.
2. Esos cambios van al Departamento de Calidad, quien verifica y certifica que todo esta correcto; si hay algún error, lo regresa a los analistas para su corrección, si esta correcto, notifica a Departamento de soporte y producción para que actualice la versión en producción.

Algunas dudas que nos surgen, es cuantas ramas deberíamos manejar? En que momento pasaría todo a la rama master? Tomando en cuenta que la cantidad de incidencias puede ser alta, es necesario crear una rama por cada incidencia a resolver?

Comment: ¿Has visto la [guía de ramas de git](https://git-scm.com/book/es/v1/Ramificaciones-en-Git) o [el flujo de trabajo de gitlab](https://about.gitlab.com/2014/09/29/gitlab-flow/)? La cantidad de ramas a usar, tiene que ver con su esquema de trabajo. [Acá](https://devtopia.coop/es/blog/desarrollo/estrategia-de-control-de-versiones-con-git) hay otro artículo sobre el tema. 
A mi entender, no hay una única verdad sobre este tema.

Comment: Lo revisaré, Gracias

Comment: Hay una [discusión](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/916/65) en [meta] sobre esta pregunta derivada del cierre de esta pregunta la cual actualmente se encuentra abierta. Aunque se han realizado algunas ediciones (yo he hecho dos) la pregunta me parece que sigue siendo demasiado amplia pero creo que antes de vota para cerrar seria mejor esperar los comentarios de un experto en [meta-tag:ingenieria-del-software]

Answer (score 1):

Una de las principales diferencias entre SVN y git es que en git crear ramas en git es muy barato, por lo tanto no  hay problema en crear una rama por cada incidencia o funcionalidad.

El flujo de trabajo que mejor se adapta a lo que planteas es el [github flow](https://guides.github.com/introduction/flow/index.html) en el cual se crea una rama por cada incidencia o funcionalidad, como se indicó antes, una vez que está listo se crea un [merge request](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/merge_requests/) el cual dispara en gitlab el motor de integración continua que se puede configurar para ejecutar los tests automatizados y para compilar el código o instalarlo en algún servidor de pruebas.

En este flujo el departamento de calidad revisaría los *merge requests* y los "aprobaría" para que el departamento de soporte para que realice el merge y actualize la versión en producción. (Estos pasos también se pueden automatizar mediante el CI.

Por último, es importante agregar que seguramente sea conveniente *tunear* un poco la configuración de gitlab para ajustarse a ese flujo de trabajo, por ejemplo, impedir los merge-requests que no son fast-forward, cuestión que agregará trabajo en el desarrollo (para mantener las ramas actualizadas) pero asegurará que el código verificado por el departamento de calidad es el que será llevado a producción.